# Disarranged login screen in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, login-screen

Whenever I wake up my computer from suspend the login screen acts kind of weirdly.

[image]

It's all the way in the top left and then jumps back to normal a second later when I start typing.

[image]

Do you have any ideas why this happens?